# How to use elasticsearch API

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch, repository

I added elasticsearch in gradle:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:1.2.5.RELEASE")
```

I created a domain class:

```
@Document(indexName = "opendata_gent", type = "details", shards = 1, replicas = 0)
public class Details {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String type;

    private Date timestamp;

    private String data;

    // getters and setters
}
```

With a repository:

```
public interface DetailsRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Details, String> {

    Details findById(String id);

    List<Details> findByType(String type);

    List<Details> findByTimestampBetween(Date beginDate, Date endDate);

    List<Details> findByTypeAndTimestampBetween(String type, Date beginDate, Date endDate);
}
```

And the service:

```
@Service
public class DetailsService {

    @Autowired
    public DetailsRepository detailsRepository;

    public Details findById(String id) {
        return detailsRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public List<Details> findByType(String type) {
        return detailsRepository.findByType(type);
    }

    public List<Details> findByTimestampBetween(Date beginDate, Date endDate) {
        return detailsRepository.findByTimestampBetween(beginDate, endDate);
    }

    public List<Details> findByTypeAndTimestampBetween(String type, Date beginDate, Date endDate) {
        return detailsRepository.findByTypeAndTimestampBetween(type, beginDate, endDate);
    }

    public void addDetails(Details details) {
        detailsRepository.save(details);
    }
}
```

I added this to my application.properties:

```
elasticsearch.host=localhost
elasticsearch.port=9300
```

What else do I need to do to be able to access elasticsearch trough the browser and get data?